# Xbooting a Java class

Tags: java, jvm, overriding, jvm-arguments

Basically I want to replace the `Canvas` class at runtime by an application that uses my custom `Canvas` class, I heard `xbooting` can do this but there are no tutorials or anything.

So I'm just wondering what the vm arguments are, can you help me please?

Comment: *"uses my custom Canvas class"*  DYM a `java.awt.Canvas`?  Time to join us in the 3rd millennium & use Swing.  BTW 1) What is the use-case here for a) Extending this class. b) Using it instead of the inbuilt class? 2) It will not be legal to distribute this app. AFAIU.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - My understanding is that it would not be legal to distribute a JVM that had the custom class instead of the standard one.  However, distributing the class together instructions on how to modify the bootclasspath would be OK.  (Doesn't make it a good idea though ...)

Comment: @StephenC  Thanks for clarifying.  Your suggestion makes more sense.

Comment: BTW  -1 for ignoring my questions.  They were intended to help you arrive at the best solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think that Francis should have answered your questions although I do not think they are relevant to the original problem and thus the downvote is not deserved. The problem is simple - how to setup a bootclasspath, that does not need to be justified by a usecase. Plus, as StephenC already pointed out, its perfectly legal to write/distribute such apps. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `xboooting` you probably mean the `-Xbootclasspath` parameter?

You can use the `-Xbootclasspath` to override the classes that are being loaded when the VM is booting. This way you can give the VM your own implementation of a certain class and it will be used right from the start of the VM. You can do something like this:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:path_to_the_jar_with_myCanvas_class.jar HelloWorld.class
```

But the `-Xbootclasspath` won't replace the `Canvas` class at runtime, the replacement will occur already at the start of the VM.

Here is a nice post about Xbootclasspath : [When to use -Xbootclasspath on HotSpot?](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.com/2012/09/when-to-use-xbootclasspath-on-hotspot.html)

Comment: Yea thats what i want haha :) just trying to figure out the rest of the parameters